# Android: Picasso image inside a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, picasso

I want to define an Android screen that has squared images in 3 columns, using the maximum width as possible.
I'm using  with a RecyclerView that uses a GridLayoutManager and Picasso for loading images.

**The problem**

I'm not able to make the images as big as possible. I've tried the following:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(factory.getImage(value)).fit().into(holder.button);
```

With this I get a correct width, but the height is resized (getting a distorted image)

```
Picasso.with(context).load(factory.getImage(value)).centerInside().fit().into(holder.button);
```

With this I get smaller images than what should be.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem with images in columns. I wanted them to have the fullest width possible and also fit into let's say 3 or 4 columns. After many experiments I realized I had forgotten to add:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

to my `ImageView`. This solved my problem. The images now fit the grid layout perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap img = Picasso.with(this).load("http://").get();
int w = img.getWidth();
int h = img.getHeight();
```

This will get you orignal height and width of an image, Now may be this would help you in yours context

Comment: The images are squared. width==height. What I need is to resize it to the  ImageView dimension.

Comment: Your target ImageView has **android:scaleType="fitXY"** property applied or not?